# How to add a sortable, drag and drop list with React/Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor, drag-and-drop

I want to add drag and drop to sort a list built with React and have the changes made by the sorting to persist in a mongodb within a Meteor app.

I’ve looked at a couple of libraries (React Dnd and Sortable-hoc) but I couldn’t move past the examples.

My collection: `recipes`, the key: `stepByStep` is an array of objects. Each object has a `stepDescription` (which is a string).

The container: `StepEditor`subscribes to `recipes` and renders the list of steps, following the order of the objects in the stepByStep array.
What I want to accomplice is to drag and drop any step and persist the change in the order in the database. Possibly in a very user-friendly way.

The container looks like this:

```
class StepsEditor extends Component {

    // Renders the list
    renderRecipeSteps( ) {

    return this.props.recipe.stepByStep.map(( step, index ) => {
        return (
            <div key={index}>
                <div>
                    <h4>{index + 1}</h4>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea defaultValue={step.stepDescription}
                              onChange={( event ) => {
                   Meteor.call( 'recipeStep.update', this.props.recipe, index,                      event.target.value );
                    }}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });

   }


    render( ) {
      return (
            <div>
                {this.renderRecipeSteps( )}
            </div>
           );
    }

}



// Create container, subscribe to `recipes`
export default createContainer( ( props ) => {
   Meteor.subscribe( 'recipes' );

   const { recipeId } = props.params;

   return ({recipe: Recipes.findOne( recipeId )});
}, StepEditor );
```